# Is it possibile to attach snippet only to specific project in Sublime?

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I tried to save the snippet files in the project folder but it is doesn't work.
Do you have any other idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## With a custom plugin

> **EDIT:** a generalisation of the following plugin has been published at
>   https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ProjectCompletions

If you put this plugin in your User folder under the name `ProjectCompletions.py`

```
import sublime_plugin

class ProjectCompletions(sublime_plugin.EventListener):

    def on_query_completions(self, view, prefix, locations):
        return view.window().project_data().get("completions")
```

You can inject completions using a `"completions"` entry in your project file:

```
{
  "folders": ...
  "completions":[
      ["I", "I am a ${1:snippet} baby!"]
  ]
}
```

The format for completions is `[trigger, snippet]`. More elaborate approaches are possible so that the scope is also taken in account.

[image: Animated Gif]

---

## In an indirect way using the [ProjectSpecific](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ProjectSpecific) plugin

With that installed, you can use the `settings` key of your project file to install additional commands.
Then to enable a snippet you can add this to your project:

```
{
    "folders": ...
    "settings": {
        "project-specific": {
            "sublime-commands": [
                {"caption": "My Snippet",
                 "command": "insert_snippet",
                 "args": {"contents": "I am a ${1:snippet} baby!"} }
            ]
        }
    ...
    }

}
```

and you'll find the "My Snippet" command in the command palette only in the current project.

You can also bind keys in a project specific way. By binding them to the `insert_snippet` command you can achieve a similar effect without having to go through the palette.

Comment: Thank you, but it is not a snippet, (snippet are autocompleted...)

Comment: @Amina with a custom plugin it is easy to get autocompletion (see edit)

Comment: WOW!!! Thank you very much, tested and working great. I want to give you half of my reputation score :)

Comment: If I find the time I will package it for Package Control, it may be useful for others too (me included!)

Comment: @Amina just published! https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ProjectCompletions (it supports scope-specific completions as well, see readme)

Comment: Added an example gif animation pull request...